# Git Sync in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2019, git-push, git-pull

I am using the Sync action from Visual Studio 2019 for getting artifacts from a git server. I know that Sync first is doing a pull operation and after that a push operation to the git server; but in my case it does not work like expected.

If I press Sync I'm receiving this message

[image: img]

But after that if I press Fetch I would expect see nothing from incoming commits, even though I'm seeing 2 incoming commits.

Any idea for this behavior?

Comment: Is this a stable scenario? I mean could it be a coincidence that between the two moments you did `sync` and then `fetch` someone managed to push something?

Comment: someone did the push along before I did the sync, this is why I considered a strange behavior

Comment: Did your remote git repo hosted on TFS server?

Comment: Yes, my git repo is hosted on TFS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As yan commented, you should first check if it's a stable scenario. If you could reproduce this issue stably.

- **sync:** performs a `git pull` and a `git push`.
- **fetch:** performs a `git fetch` which retrieves any commits on from
  your remote without merging them.

This is not an expect behavior. You could use `git reflog` command to track the logs and check if there is some useful information.

You could also have a try with remote git repo hosted by other sever such as GitHub. This will narrow down if it's a client side issue.

Also upgrade your VS2019 to latest version, which may do the trick.